# How to create a custom Facebook “Like” button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-like

Custom Facebook like button

1. Change Background image
2. Change frame
3. Text color change

Answer (score 1):

- Create a `UIButton`. Set a custom image/Color and custom frame in xib/storyboard. Set the `sent event` for Touch up inside. (Till now you have created a normal button)
- Handle the button action as follows:-

// MARK: - Facebook Button Action

```
enter code here

@IBAction func Facebook_Tapped(sender: AnyObject)
{    
    let fbHandller = HMFacebookHandler.sharedInstance
    fbHandller.delegate = self
    fbHandller.InitiateForFacebookSignIn()
}
```

- Set the `Facebook delegate` methods in same viewcontroller. For eg:- `facebookSignInFailed`, `facebookSignInSucceed`, `facebookSignInCancelled`

My login view which have the custom social login buttons:-

[image]